# JsPDF - Image cut on little screen

Tags: reactjs, d3.js, jspdf

I have a program coding for take 3 svg (axis y1, graph with axis x1 at bottom, axis y2) and creating a pdf with it.
In the code for create the pdf, before I create the svg

```
var source = d3.select("body")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("height", this.node.clientHeight + this.node.clientHeight/10)
    .attr("width", this.node.clientWidth + 65*2 + this.node.clientWidth/20)
    .attr('version', 1.1)
    .attr('xmlns', 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg')
    .html(d3.select(".svgaxisy").node().innerHTML+"<g transform='translate(65,10)'>"+d3.select(this.node).node().innerHTML+"</g>"+
        "<g transform='translate("+(this.node.clientWidth + ((this.node.clientWidth/this.nested_data.length)/20) + 65)+",0)'>"+d3.select(".svgaxisy2").node().innerHTML+"</g>");
```

After setting the value for width and height for jsPDF I put the source into `SaveSvgAsPng` npm module to give me a link with image. I put that image in JsPDF to transform it into a pdf.
(I have already tested with `saveSvgAsPng` to download png and this worked as expected)

```
saveSvgAsPng.svgAsPngUri(source.node(), {}, function(uri) {
    const pdf = new jsPDF("landscape", 'px', [more_height, more_width]);
    pdf.addImage(uri, 'PNG', 0, 0);
    pdf.save("graph.pdf");
    d3.select(source.node()).remove();
}.bind(this));
```

So that work, on my big screen it give me a full graph but on a laptop with little screen it only display the half graph.

Comment: Were you able to resolve that? I bet it has to do with DPI. Are you using windows on both devices?

Comment: @Mike Yes I have solve that, we are on Mac, I change to use `save-svg-as-png` npm module

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So for the solution, I decide to use npm module `save-svg-as-png` with that code:

```
var source = d3.select("body")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("height", this.node.clientHeight + this.node.clientHeight/10)
    .attr("width", this.node.clientWidth + 65*2 + this.node.clientWidth/20)
    .attr('version', 1.1)
    .attr('xmlns', 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg')
    .html(d3.select(".svgaxisy").node().innerHTML+"<g transform='translate(65,10)'>"+d3.select(this.node).node().innerHTML+"</g>"+
        "<g transform='translate("+(this.node.clientWidth + ((this.node.clientWidth/this.nested_data.length)/20) + 65)+",0)'>"+d3.select(".svgaxisy2").node().innerHTML+"</g>");

saveSvgAsPng.saveSvgAsPng(source.node(), "graph.png");
```